# May I use portage on ChromiumOS natively?

Tags: package-management, google-chrome-os, chromebook, portage

May I unlock Portage on ChromiumOS or reinstall it natively without jails and other 'install linux inside ChromiumOS' approaches? May I use Gentoo default repository then?

#### Why

1. I like ChromiumOS look and feel (`Freon`, not `X11` or `Chromixium`).
2. I want to develop in terminal with `vim`, `neovim`, `Node.js` or others.
3. I need package manager and a wide choice of packages (`chrombrew` seems not enough).
4. I want to avoid emulation/virtualization layer solution like `crouton`.

Comment: I'm also very interested in this question. However, what do you find wrong with chromebrew? It should install packages that it does not include binaries for from source. Disclaimer: I haven't tried it myself yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes (kind of), its possible and its even officially documented:

- emerge for installing packages under /usr/local in stateful partition https://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/how-tos-and-troubleshooting/install-software-on-base-images
- gmerge for installing packages into the base system (note that space is limited and you need to remove rootfs protection which is not too secure) https://www.chromium.org/chromium-os/how-tos-and-troubleshooting/using-the-dev-server#TOC-How-to-build-a-single-package-and-install-it-without-doing-a-full-update
- yes they seem to have portage default repository in arms www.chromium.org/chromium-os/gentoo-package-upgrade-process

Please note that with how Google makes things, you'll need a devserver - i.e. you need to prepare chroot or VM on your Chrome device or use an external machine for actual package building.

Comment: ChromiumOS docs were always cryptic to me. Thank you. I'm curious why can't you make your system a client and a _"devserver"_ at the same time without `chroot`. Maybe because two different Portage configurations are needed: bindist for a client and `gmerge` with non-binary main repository.

Comment: It may be theoretically possible to do self-hosting, but no hand of help from Google here :( At very minimum toolchain packages must be landed to Chromium OS target device, so portage could build packages from sources right there.